# JSP Tag Spacing Regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, jsp

We are suppose to migrate all our apps from one type of server to another. The new servers do not accept invalid JSP tags where a space is not inserted between the attributes. For example, the following.

```
<input type="text"name="myField" />
```

The following regex was given to us to use, but it seems to not be perfect.

```
[\w.-]+[\s]*=[\s]*"[^"]+"[^\s/%>]
```

For example, it returns string assignments like the following.

```
span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

Can anyone suggest a better regex for locating just the invalid JSP code?

**UPDATE**

I was this regex to work using the Eclipse Search > File functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this RegEx: `(<.+?[^" ]+?="[^"]+?")([^ ]+?)(.+?>)`. Will locate all "tags" with a `"` not followed by a space. Then you can replace the captured groups like this: `$1 $2$3` to add a space.

Comment: Although this found the problematic code, it made the search results go from 50 to 4,600.

Comment: It returns `<div id="myDiv">` for example.

Comment: Are you sure there's not just 4,600 missing spaces? If so, can you give a larger code sample please? `<div id="myDiv">` does not match, I just tested it in SublimeText. [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) also does not match. Maybe you need to escape the `<>`?

Comment: The original regex also found the invalid tags, but also some false positives. I've browsed the results of your regex and it looks like it's mostly false positives.

Comment: Returns `<div id="myDiv">`, `<td align="center">`, `<jsp:include page="..."/>`, etc.

Comment: I am running in Eclipse with Search > File and checking the Regular Expression box.

Comment: My guess it has something to do with your IDE or JSP, not the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Tenub's answer is nearly correct, but as Rachel G. mentioned, it will return false positives when the closing bracket immediately follows the closing quotation mark.

(<[^?%].+?[^" ]+?="[^"]+?")([^/ >]+?)([^>]*(?:/|\?|%)?>)

Should give you the results you're after.

Disclaimer: This is not a strict checker.  You could have a tag such as <..." asdf/> go undetected, but as the tags are presumably well formed enough to work under the old system, this should be sufficient.

Comment: I think this is almost right. It looks like it returns things if they are closed w/o a closing tag. For example `<jsp:include page="..."/>`. I could fix the 1,800 or so to have a space before the close, but that would be a lot of work. Is there a way to stop finding those?

Comment: Ideally, it would also not catch XML statements like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Am I picky or what? :)

Comment: I've updated the regex to hopefully be more useful to you; again, it isn't going completely check validity of the tag, but it should give you far fewer false positives.

Comment: Getting better. The only 2 main things left are taglibs `<%@ taglib uri="..." prefix="..."%>` and elements that were broken into different lines with newlines (such as `<c:foreach` and `<option value="..." `. I think #2 would be a pain to fix, but maybe not #1? I am searching to see if there was anything else major false positive wise.

Comment: Also `<forward name="..." path="..."/>` which I find weird since it looks like this was handled other places.

Comment: There must be something in the name or path value that's causing it to find those, as I can't reproduce that one.  Updated for taglib, but without being able to see the values in one of the forward tags I don't know what's causing it to trip up.

Comment: The path usually has slashes. `<forward name="justLetters" path="/letters-letters/letters/letters.extension"/>`

Comment: Must be something different between our regex evaluators.  I don't get a hit on the <forward /> tag; hopefully someone else can solve that last bit.

Comment: Was I correct that the other issue is hard to correct? Where multi-line tags get returned. For example, `<img` and `<img src="..."`.

Comment: If you were to run the regex against a flattened string version of the jsps then you would be able to find issues with the multi-line tags without modifying the regex (you would need to strip out tabs, newlines and "extra" spaces when building the string representation).
A non-regex solution might be more useful as the problem is getting to be more of an irregular language issue than a regular one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

- **Find:** `(=\s*"[^"]*")(\w)`
- **Replace with:** `$1 $2`

#### Explanation

The *find* regex looks for `=` followed by *optional whitespace* followed by `"`...`"`, immediately followed by a single alphanumeric character or underscore.
It's separated out into two capturing groups, which are represented by $1 and $2 in the replace expression - with a space inserted between them.

[**Minor Issue:** This won't work for attribute values that include escaped double quotation marks. Haven't addressed this as am assuming it is pretty unlikely. However, it justifies doing a manual find/replace rather than "replace all" just in case.]

Comment: Could you give an example of where it wouldn't work? I don't know what you mean by escaping the quotes.

Comment: By escaping the quotes I mean using a backslash followed by a quotation mark (`\"`) to make it a literal. E.g: `<navi:out text="Hello \"world\" />` - see [JSP Quoting rules](http://etc.to/jsp_quoting_rules)